# Service orientated SDLC

Tags: sdlc

Are there any service oriented software development methodologies?

Comment: It's not like you're using your real name, so nobody ever needs to know, but 'orientated' is not really a word. It's status is similar to irregardless. Sure, non-standard English makes you stand out, a little like hitting your thumb with a hammer makes your thumb stand out

Comment: It looks like an honest mistake to me - it's spelt correctly in the body of the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that... it's been a long day :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm most aware of IBM's SOMA http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-soa-design1/

I'm sure there are others and will add them in.  Here is a starting point with some suggestions: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/the-soa-blog/serviceoriented-architecture-soa-methodology-12022

Some of this depends on if you're interested in the overall architecture which the points above aim at, or if you're more interested in the development of specific components within your SOA e.g. methodologies for developing specific services on your ESB etc.

More details and links for further reading at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soad1/

Comment: Thanks Kris!
I will be reading over these this evening.

Your help has been greatly appreciated